# Why I get "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, axios, backend

When I try to render a contact list for the current user from MongoDB,  I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined." error. However, the URL already includes the current user's id, and I checked it is the same id saved on MongoDB. I don't understand why it still shows id is undefined. [image]

```js
module.exports.getAllUsers = async (res, req, next) => {
  try {
    const users = await Users.find({ _id: { $ne: req.params.id } }).select([
      "email",
      "username",
      "avatarImage",
      "_id",
    ]);
    return res.json(users);
  } catch (ex) {
    next(ex);
  }
};
```

Comment: `req.params` is `undefined`, therefore `req.params.id` throws an error. The reason is that `req` should be the `first` parameter, not the second.

Comment: @VLAZ OMG! Thanks, bro. I didn't realize it. 